# Adjust width and height when screen size is reduced

Tags: css

How do you make width and height of a circle that I made automatically reduced according to its screen size?

I set the width and height to `40px`

Code:

```
.circle {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #b7b7b7;
    margin-right: 2%;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: ease-in .5s;
    -o-transition: ease-in .5s;
    -moz-transition: ease-in .5s;
    transition: ease-in .5s;
}
```

I tried using calc for width and height using this

```
width:calc(100% - 40px);
height:calc(100% - 40px);
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I heard some sources that calc is the key for this one. I am working with a container of **1920px** and minimum screen size is **320px**. Is there any proper way to implement calc function for width and height?

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried with media query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vw` and `vh` (1% of available width and height respectively) partnered with media query. An example:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  .circle {
    width: calc(100% - 5vw);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this sir. the reducing of the width and height should be 1920px start.. should I try min-width:320px ?